# Is there a way in the Couchbase Java SDK to not list the nodes to connect to?

Tags: java, couchbase

Today I see people in example code do a list of FQDNs or IPs for nodes in the cluster to bootstrap connection string for the application code. Is there a different/better way of doing this? Something that does not require maintaining the list in a file, code or somewhere?

Comment: What example code are you looking at?

Comment: In the docs it show something like this.

Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("192.168.56.101", "192.168.56.102");

I do not want to list out the IPs or FQDNS and maintain that in code in case I need to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found it. You can use a DNS SRV record. It is buried at the bottom of the managing connections page of the newer documentation under "Bootstrapping through DNS SRV". http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.1/managing-connections.html